# Regular expression that handles a 3-digit number OR a hyphen

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to handle blood pressures ex: "145/80"
Some blood pressures come with an empty value ex: "-/80" or "145/-"

I have this right now to handle the numbers, but how can I handle the hyphen? ^\d{1,3}/\d{1,3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OR expression ( `|` ) in your regex:

```
^(\d{1,3}|-)/(\d{1,3}|-)$
```

- `(\d{1,3}|-)` - one to three digits OR hyphen
- `/` - slash
- `(\d{1,3}|-)` - one to three digits OR hyphen

Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/iyKNHr/1)

Comment: No capturing or anchors needed: `String patBP = "(?:-|\\d{1,3})/(?:\\d{1,3}|-)";`

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` for "or":

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class BloodPressure {
    private static final String numbersOrDash = "(-|\\d{1,3})";
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + numbersOrDash + "/" + numbersOrDash + "$");

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String a : args) {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(a);
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println(a + " looks like a blood pressure");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(a + " does not look like a blood pressure");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added the `^` and `$` to anchor the regex to the beginning and ends of the input, respectively, so that e.g., "abc1/-" does not match.

Pass some test values:

```
robert:~$ java BloodPressure.java  a 20/- -/20 80/120
a does not look like a blood pressure
20/- looks like a blood pressure
-/20 looks like a blood pressure
80/120 looks like a blood pressure
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only find `systolic` and `diastolic` as a unit.

- `|` or
- `\\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits

```
 String s = "-/80 120 abc -120  120/-  80-  80 de  120/80";
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}|-)/(\\d{1,3}|-)").matcher(s);
 while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

prints

```
-/80
120/-
120/80
```